# Replace function, how to assign "b" multiple values?

Tags: python, replace

My problem is very small, and is that I can't do a normal letter substitution. I know the .replace command, but I can't seem to use it correctly.

**For example**: My k##yb0%%rd is br###k##n. ### should be replaced with o, ## with e, and %% with a. Thanks!

```
a = input("What did she say? ")
b = a.replace("###", "o")
print(b)
```

Comment: What have you tried for replacing the latter two sequences?

Comment: how calling replace again `c = b.replace("", "")` ? or chain them ? `b = a.replace("", "").replace("", "")`

Comment: have you tried `string = string.replace("###", "o").replace("%%", "a").replace("##", "e")`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
a = input("What did she say? ")
d = {'###':'o', '##':'e','%%':'a'}
for k,v in d.items():
    a = a.replace(k, v)
b = a # if you need value in b variable
print(b)
```

You can create such dictionary and use it replace multiple values. Make sure to properly arrange your dictionary.

Comment: Thank you very much! Can you please explain me in details, how this dictionary works?

Comment: @Andriy we are creating a dictionary with key as the string you need to replace and value as the string you want to insert. So here while looping in dictionary: in the first iteration, the value of k is ### and the value of v is o. So first it will replace ### with o  and assign it to same 'a' variable. in next iteration the value of k is ## and value of v is e. In this it will replace ## with e and assign to again 'a' variable. And this will go for all values.

Answer (score 1):

As the first thing I would suggest to read the Python's documentation for [`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace).

---

I would suggest something like this:

```
b = a.replace("###", 'o').replace("##", 'e').replace("%%", 'a')
```

This is possible because the `return`ed value of `a.replace("###", 'o')` is of type `str`, so that the method `replace` can be applied on it too.

---

If you don't know which characters will be replaced, you should do like suggested by [`Vaibhav`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12543191/vaibhav), creating a `dict` that associates old chars (key) with new chars (value).

---

What's more `str` is an immutable `type`, so you can't just do

```
a.replace("###", 'o').replace("##", 'e').replace("%%", 'a')
```

but anyway you don't have to assign the returned value to `b`, you can't reassign it to `a` without problems:

```
a = a.replace("###", 'o').replace("##", 'e').replace("%%", 'a')
```

and you can `print` it directly too.

Comment: This will be difficult if in case there would be many strings to replace.

Comment: I know what you mean, your idea which uses a dict is good in this case, I was just showing how to do it in the case of the example provided. Anyway +1 for you.

Comment: Yup just thought that it would be difficult :-) +1 for you as well. :-)